# How to access to home page's html source code

Tags: wordpress, html, pagelines

In wordpress I use a building page editor plugin, (PageLines).

I have pasted a Google map script in the home page (by a simple html block), using PageLines building. 
Now, after the script, PageLines has blocked for the home page and it doesn't work. So I can't access to home page code and I can't remove the script.

If I cancel the PageLines plugin, the script in the home page is cancelled, but if I reinstall PageLines plugin, the script automatically is rewrited.

How can I access to home page source code and remove the script?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a solution to remove the script is to edit the Homepage not with builder editor but with the wp text editor. Then find the script and remove those lines. See image below.

[image: Wordpress Text Editor]

Comment: Thanks for your suggest, I'm trying to use wp text editor, but I can use it only on others pages and contents, not on home page. Is it possible?

Comment: Try it with deactivating the PageLines plugin?

Comment: Yes, without plugin the script was cancelled, but I need that plugin.

Comment: Now, I have solved with a new home page (static page).

Comment: Did you create a new home page?

Answer (score 0):

At moment I have solved with a new home page (static page),
I hope it will work well.

Here how build easy a new homepage:
https://www.webhostinghero.com/wordpress-how-to-edit-the-home-page/